# Calculating Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index (SAVI) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, savi

I want to calculate the SAVI in Google Earth Engine. I am using the formula as below:

```
((NIR-Red)/(NIR+Red+0.5))*1.5
```

The value range should come between -1 to 1.

I am using Sentinel 2 image. But after the calculation, the lower value range is within -1. But the upper-value range is going beyond 1. I am using the following code below.

Am I calculating it in the wrong way?

```
    //Load the study area
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/swadhinakoley/Hazaribagh_geo');
Map.addLayer(studyarea, {}, 'studyarea');

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var S2_display = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};

function addsa(input){
  var NIR = input.select('B8');
  var RED = input.select('B4');
  var sa_neu = NIR.subtract(RED);
  var sa_deno = NIR.add(RED).add(0.5);
  var sa = sa_neu.multiply(1.5).divide(sa_deno).rename('savi');
  return input.addBands(sa);
}

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterDate('2019-04-15', '2019-05-31')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 1)
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)})
  .map(addsa);

var savi_S2 = S2.select('savi').max();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: savi_S2,
  description: 'SAVI_Gumla2_Z',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry6
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the band description in the dataset [catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2#bands), you'll notice that the the red and NIR band have a scale of `0.0001`, meaning the values are between `0` and `10000` instead between `0` and `1`. So, you need to multiply your bands with the scale.

```
input = input.multiply(0.0001)
```

For a simple normalized difference, this makes no difference, but in this case it does matter. With the correctly scaled bands, if `NIR = 1` and `Red = 0`, you'll get `(1/(1+0.5))*1.5`, which is `1`. `NIR = 100000` and `Red = 0`, you'll get `(10000/(10000+0.5))*1.5` which is close to `1.5`.

I typically use expression strings for non-trivial calculations. Here's how it would look for you, just copy/pasting the formula you had in the question:

```
function addsa(input) {
  var sa = ee.Image().expression('((NIR-Red)/(NIR+Red+0.5))*1.5', {
    NIR: input.select('B8').multiply(0.0001),
    Red: input.select('B4').multiply(0.0001)
  }).rename('savi')
  return input.addBands(sa)
}
```

Comment: Okay! Now I get it. Thanks!